# Android - can I change exit buttons on Screen Pinning?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-screen-pinning

In 5.0 Android add Screen Pinning: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

I call in my app calling `startLockTask()` but for exit the app user always need to " holding both the Back and Recent buttons"

Can I change these and choose my own buttons combination?

Answer (score 0):

The API says there is a complementary stopLockTask() function so you can assign a custom button to call that. However, I don't think you can change the navigation buttons combination.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#stopLockTask()